# How can I use slider input with swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html5-video, swipe

I'm building an html application for mobile devices (to be used with PhoneGap) and I'm using swiper by idangero.us to make page transitions.

In one of the pages, I have an html5 video tag but every time I try to use the volume slider, swiper gets activated.
How can I avoid that?

For example, consider the following:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <video src="some_movie_url" controls></video>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            Foo
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            Bar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {speed: 250, freeMode: false});
```

Is there any "easy" way to make the video controls work? or should I capture all swiping events and handle them myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prevent Swiper events when "touching" video element using stopPropagation:

```
$('video').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir.
I no longer have access to this project so I can't verify your answer but wouldn't that also prevent the video controls from working? (e.g. the volume bar)